# Playing videos in UITableViewCell with AVPlayer always getting AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, video, avplayer

im trying to play videos from url in UITableViewCell with AVPlayer (not exactly like instagram do but close enough)

I'm trying to play the videos one at a time.
When i tap the "play" button in the cell, the video starts to play but only for 1 or 2 seconds, then i get an AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification.

I declared in CustomTableViewCell.h

```
  @property AVPlayer *player;
  @property AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
  @property AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer;
  @property AVAsset *playerAsset;
  @property NSString *playerUrl;
```

Then i have an IBAction in my ViewController.m

```
 - (IBAction)play:(id)sender {

   CustomCell *clickedCell = (CustomCell *)[[sender superview] superview];

   clickedCell.btnPlay.hidden = YES;

   clickedCell.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:clickedCell.playerUrl]];

   clickedCell.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:clickedCell.playerItem];
   clickedCell.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:clickedCell.player];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserverForName:AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification
    object:clickedCell.playerItem
    queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

        NSLog(@"%@ -> %ld", @"AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification", (long)[clickedCell.playerItem status]);

 }];

   [clickedCell.playerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width)];
   [clickedCell.iamgen.layer addSublayer:clickedCell.playerLayer];
   [clickedCell.playerLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];

   [clickedCell.iamgen.layer addSublayer:clickedCell.playerLayer];

   [clickedCell.player play];

}
```

The clickedCell.iamgen is because i have a UIIMageView where i present a preview image for the video.

What is the reason why i get always the stalled notification? The internet connection?? Which is the best way to implement this scenario??

Sorry for my english!

EDIT:
I'm pretty sure is becaus the buffer doesn't load fast enough. The reason i think this is because if i tap the play button repeatedly after the AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification is like the video go forward frame by frame. I think the idea is to know when the buffer is fully enough that i can continue playng.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you play back a local file? Are the assets you are using HLS?

Comment: i didn't try in local. For the 2nd question, i don't know, i'm pretty much newbie with this. I'm taking the video from a url in my server (like http://myserver.com/video.mp4)

Comment: The data rate of the video may be higher than the connection and transport can allow. Using HLS would definitely be an improvement and can prevent an App Store rejection.

Comment: Do you have a guide on how to implement HLS on my server? I have nginx installed if ir works

Comment: Any HTTP server works. It's mostly a matter of how the content is encoded and formatted. Look at the HTTP live streaming documents on the Apple developer portal.

Comment: I will look at it. But i think is more an implementation in my code because the video out of the tableview works fine. Thanks!